# in the Scheme language, a code that returns a list with all prime numbers less than or equal to n

Tags: scheme

I have been writing a code that returns a list with all prime numbers less than or equal to n in the Scheme language.
Example,3 -> 2,3 10 -> 1,3,5,7 11->2,3,5,7,11
Actually, the codes below works.However, when I put 1 for n, the code should show (), but it shows  2. I think that it is because I put 2 on the second line. But I put the 2 for the other test case.
I tried to fix the code, but it did not work.
Are there any points where I can fix?

```
(define (primes n)
    (let loop((result `(2))
             (i 3))      
      (cond ((> i n)(reverse result))
            (else (loop
                   (if (divide-any? i result) result (cons i result))
                   (+ i 2))))))


    

    (define (divide? n1 n2)
      (zero? (modulo n1 n2)))

    

    (define (divide-any? n ls)
      (do ((ls ls (cdr ls)))
          ((or (null? ls)
               (divide? n (car ls)))
           (not (eqv? '() ls)))))
```

Comment: Sorry for the indent,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the function `primes` is `partial` - it only works for certain values.

You can fix it quite simply:

```
(define (primes n)
    (if (<= n 1)
        '()
    (let loop((result `(2))
             (i 3))      
      (cond ((> i n)(reverse result))
            (else (loop
                   (if (divide-any? i result) result (cons i result))
                   (+ i 2)))))))
```

Comment: I tried that and it worked! I really apreciate your help!